# blog news with inside article summary and login form to read the whole article

Tags: joomla-4.x

I have a need to create a news section but which is password protected via login form. What I can't find is the ability to show a small summary of the article and then show the login/registration form right below. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

I use Joomla 4 and if it can be useful Yootheme

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're wanting to show the summaries, even though the website visitor isn't logged on. But when they click on a link to the article associated with a summary then they don't see it if they haven't logged on.

If that's what you're looking to do then you could create a Content custom field (eg of type editor field), and use that to hold the summary associated with each article.

Then you could write a module which queried the database and output the summaries together with links to the associated articles. You'd have to do the query yourself, joining across the `content`, `fields` and `fields_values` tables, but that's straightforward.

I'm not sure how comfortable you are with creating joomla modules, but if you search online for "joomla module development" you'll find good tutorials, including at https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase a sample module which queries the database. A Joomla 3 module should work ok under Joomla 4. And you can always post a comment or raise another question on this forum if you get stuck.